# Was Alexander Gerst the first man to have bare skin exposed to the vacuum of space and live?

Tags: iss, astronauts, record, spaceflight-firsts, leak

On August 30, 2018, a hole was found in the Soyuz Orbital Module on the ISS. Astronaut Alexander Gerst initially plugged it with his thumb, meaning a part of his bare skin touched space. I can't find any other instances of someone touching the vacuum of space with his or her bare skin, except for the Soyuz 11 crew who died. Was Alexander Gerst the first person to touch space with his bare skin and live?

Comment: Wasn't one of the first suborbital/orbital flights by a man who wasn't in a properly pressurized vessel? Meaning he was basically subjected to the depressurized environment for a few seconds before he immediately began descending to save his own life? Needs verification, I cannot remember his name nor the vessel he flew on, will try to find where this was stated on this site (I believe it was sourced).

Comment: That would be interesting, but not quite space. Still. Hmmm... Looking around, there has been a few high altitude, but not actually by any reasonable definition outside the atmosphere incidences. http://www.geoffreylandis.com/vacuum.html

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Since it's just one atmosphere of pressure inside the ISS, it's safe to plug the hole with your bare skin. Just a bit uncomfortable after a while. [Scott Manley linked a video](https://twitter.com/DJSnM/status/1035661990411169792) regarding this.

Comment: @DarkDust I am picturing an thumb-sized hole where there would be significant thumb outside of the station (guessing that would've been much more of a problem though), statement retracted. Interesting video link too. Thanks!

Comment: Would this change things: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30451/did-nasa-publish-then-delete-this-and-other-photos-of-the-iss-leak (if the outer hull is intact, did he not actually touch space)?

Comment: Related (not really but kind of, sorta): http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/aerospace-engineering/space-suit-design/early-spacesuit-vacuum-test-wrong/

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn "touch space" seems a bit tricky to define. If the outer hull wasn't pressurised, then even if it blocked a direct line of sight to the outside world, it was still vacuum...

Comment: I felt free to make the question's title less clickbaity and more accurate. Hope you're fine with it.

Comment: Like the question. But would you also accept answers that give references to people on Earth sealing holes of (very strong) vacuum chambers with their fingers?

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut: Tim: We can only accept one answer, although we can upvote more than one. The question really was if there had been others to do it in space, so I accepted that answer, although I will give you there is some value in the other answer. I already knew that in small amounts it could be safe, such as just a finger tip, but I wasn't sure if others had done it before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. It occurred previously on [STS-37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-37) in 1991. During an EVA, a glove was punctured; the astronaut's hand almost immediately sealed the hole. They didn't notice (remarkable as that sounds) until after flight; there's a brief mention of it on [the page](http://www.geoffreylandis.com/vacuum.html) PearsonArtPhoto linked to in comments:

> "...the palm restraint in one of the astronaut's gloves came loose and migrated until it punched a hole in the pressure bladder between his thumb and forefinger. It was not explosive decompression, just a little 1/8 inch [3 mm] hole, but it was exciting down here in the swamp because it was the first injury we've ever head from a suit incident. Amazingly, the astronaut in question didn't even know the puncture had occured; he was so hopped on adrenalin it wasn't until after he got back in that he even noticed there was a painful red mark on his hand. He figured his glove was chafing and didn't worry about it.... What happened: when the metal bar punctured the glove, the skin of the astronaut's hand partially sealed the opening. He bled into space, and at the same time his coagulating blood sealed the opening enough that the bar was retained inside the hole."

[Mission report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930016767.pdf):

> The EV2 crewman reported during postflight debriefings that following the second EVA and after removal of  the gloves, the right-hand index finger had an abrasion about 3/4 inch [2 cm] behind the metacarpal knuckle. The postflight inspection of the right-hand glove revealed that the palm bar was penetrating through the restraint and glove bladder into the index finger side of the glove approximately [5?]/8 inch [1.6 cm] (Flight Problem STS-37-V-19). The glove leakage rate with the palm bar in the failed position was 3.8 [sccm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCCM_(flow_unit)) of air as compared with the specification rate of 8.0 sccm. Had  the palm bar come out of the hole during the EVA, the leak rate would not have been great enough to activate the secondary oxygen pack. The primary oxygen system would have maintained satisfactory suit pressure, and would also have displayed a high oxygen usage rate indication.

Comment: Technically "No"  would sound better against the title (but that's semantics), amazing how blood coagulating could seal a hole like that. May also be worthy of note that the typed sections are on page 16.

Answer (score 3):

This supplemental answer addresses how dangerous "touching space" would be in the context of a small hole.

The *vacuum* of space is not much different than the vacuum of a vacuum pump from the point of view of a finger over a small hole.

Watching Scott Manley for a few minutes in the first video you'll see he mentions the second video, which shows a screen shot of Manley's idea to "touch space".

Mechanical roughing pumps similar to the one in the video can probably produce about 50 milliTorr absolute. The video says the pressure differential is 12 psi because 12 psi is the absolute pressure at the altitude where this video was recorded.

Was the finger damaged?

Spoiler alert: hover your cursor over the box to reveal the answer.

> No fingers were injured in the filming of this video

Comment: But it is possible to injure other parts of the body with a much lower pressure difference, see [hickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hickey).